# How transfer 64 bit integers from C to R?

Tags: c, r

I want to create a vector of `long long` in C/C++ and then transfer them to R. I want to do it only by using R standard C API functionality.

For example in case of 32 bit integers I do this

```
extern "C" __declspec( dllexport ) SEXP my_func()
{
    SEXP int_vec;
    PROTECT(int_vec = allocVector(REALSXP, 2));
    int a=10, b=20;
    INTEGER(int_vec)[0] = a;
    INTEGER(int_vec)[1] = b;

    UNPROTECT(1);
    return int_vec;
}
```

How can I do it for `long long`? What should I use instead of `INTEGER`?

Comment: Look at [bit64](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bit64/index.html) and/or [int64](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/int64/index.html) to see how those authors did it.

Comment: R does not have `long long`, you may just want to convert to `double`.